# C# WPF add/update items to menu during runtime using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menu

I am working on an application where it is required to add/update/remove items to the menu control. The menu is swapped to an usercontrol. The items are VMs and I bound the list of it to the usercontrol. When I start the application, all works as expected, but the view will not update if I change the list of items, but inside the MainViewModel, the list will do. Is it possible to do something like this? All the VMs are derrived from a base type which inherits "PropertyChanged".

MenuItemViewModel:

```
    public class MenuItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly ICommand _command;
        private int _minUserRole = 0;
        private object _cmdParam;

        public MenuItemViewModel(ICommand command, int minUserRole, object cmdParam)
        {
            _command = command;
            _minUserRole = minUserRole;
            _cmdParam = cmdParam;
        }

        public ICommand Command { get { return _command; } }

        public object CmdParam
        { get { return _cmdParam; } }

        public int MinUserRole 
        { 
            get 
            { return _minUserRole; }
            set 
            {
                _minUserRole = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MinUserRole));
            }
        }

        public string Header { get; set; }

        public bool HasSubmenu => SubMenuItems != null;

        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> SubMenuItems { get; set; }
    }
```

MenuMain xaml:

```
   <StackPanel Name="MainPanel"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="0 10"
                Background="Transparent"
                Width="250"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        
        <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemsPanel>

            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CmdParam}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SubMenu_Template}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RoleToEnableConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Role" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}">
                                </Binding>
                                <Binding Path="MinUserRole" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                        DataType="{x:Type vms:MenuItemViewModel}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubMenuItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <cmp:MenuItemTemplate/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Menu.ItemTemplate>
        </Menu>
    </StackPanel>
```

MainWindow xaml

```
            <cmp:MenuMain Grid.Column="0"
                IsOpen="{Binding MenuIsOpen}"
                OpenCloseDuration="0:0:10"
                Role="{Binding ActualUsersRole}">
            </cmp:MenuMain>
```

MainViewModel:

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<MenuItemViewModel> _menuItems;

        public IList<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems
        { 
            get
                {
                    return _menuItems;
                }
            set
            {
                _menuItems = (List<MenuItemViewModel>)value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MenuItems));
            }
        }

        public ICommand SwitchViewCommand { get;}
        public ICommand SwitchRoomsViewCommand { get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            SwitchUsersViewCommand = new NavigateCommand(usersNavigationService);
            SwitchRoomsViewCommand = new ParameterNavigateCommand(roomsNavigationService);

            _menuItems = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();
            LoadMenu();
        }

        private void LoadMenu()
        {
            //Navigate Commands
            MenuCommand SwitchToUser = new MenuCommand(SwitchUsersViewCommand, this);
            MenuCommand SwitchToList = new MenuCommand(SwitchFfuListViewCommand, this);
            MenuCommand SwitchRooms = new MenuCommand(SwitchRoomsViewCommand, this);

            _menuItems.Clear();
            MenuItemViewModel TmpItem = new MenuItemViewModel(null, 0, null) { Header = "Home" };
            _menuItems.Add(TmpItem);
            TmpItem = new MenuItemViewModel(null, 0, null) { Header = "Rooms" };

            //--> Adding structures to Submenu

            //ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> TmpSubList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();
            //foreach (var item in _structuresStore.Structures)
            //{
            //    if (item == null) continue;
            //    MenuItemViewModel TmpSubItem = new MenuItemViewModel(SwitchRooms, 0, item) { Header = item.StructureName };
            //    TmpSubList.Add(TmpSubItem);
            //}
            //TmpItem.SubMenuItems = TmpSubList;
            _menuItems.Add(TmpItem);

            //--> temporary adding structures to MainMenu

            foreach (var item in _structuresStore.Structures)
            {
                if (item == null) continue;
                TmpItem = new MenuItemViewModel(SwitchRooms, 0, item) { Header = item.StructureName };
                _menuItems.Add(TmpItem);
            }


            TmpItem = new MenuItemViewModel(SwitchToUser, 3, null) { Header = "Users" };
            _menuItems.Add(TmpItem);
            TmpItem = new MenuItemViewModel(SwitchToList, 1, null) { Header = "List" };
            _menuItems.Add(TmpItem);
            MenuItems = _menuItems;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MenuItems));
        }
    }
    public class MenuCommand : CommandBase
    {
        private readonly ICommand _iCmd;
        private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel;

        public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get { return _mainViewModel; } }

        public MenuCommand(ICommand iCmd, MainViewModel mvm)
        {
            _iCmd = iCmd;
            _mainViewModel = mvm;
        }

        public override void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            _mainViewModel.MenuIsOpen = false;
            if (!(_iCmd == null))
            {
                _iCmd.Execute(parameter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.
best regards Daniel

Comment: The control has no way of knowing when you add or remove items (OnPropertyChange only fires when you replace it with a whole new list object).  Make your MenuItems an ObservableCollection instead, this will notify when the collection changes.

Comment: Hi Tarazed, I tried this already, but no success. The collection, holding the MenuItemViewModels, is updatet, but not the Menu.